# Why doesnt work regex

Tags: regex, erlang, pattern-matching

Code Example

```
14> case re:run("5162754", "/^\d+$/") of {match, _} -> ok end.
** exception error: no case clause matching nomatch  
15> case re:run(<<"5162754">>, "/^\d+$/") of {match, _} -> ok end.
** exception error: no case clause matching nomatch
```

Why doesn't it match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. The regular expression you pass to `re:run` shouldn't be surrounded by `/`. In other languages, you write a regexp inside `/` signs, but in Erlang, regexps are always written as strings, and thus no `/` signs are necessary.
2. In an Erlang string, `\d` represents the "delete" character (code 127).  What you actually want in your regexp is a backslash followed by the letter `d`.  To achieve that, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash:

   ```
   > re:run("5162754", "^\\d+$").
   {match,[{0,7}]}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [0-9] it will also works and no problems with backslashes

```
re:run("5162754", "^[0-9]+$").
```